E1 extruder error encountered while printing - what to do?
My Ender 2 Pro started alarming (thought it was my laptop at first, though it was my printer beeping loudly upstairs).
I checked the screen to read an error with the extruder. The screen showed an E1 Extruder error. Critical error, printer halted.
Silicon sock is there, and stuff seems fine by exterior inspection. What should I do to troubleshoot this error?

Hi and welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! What was the exact message, and did you make a photo of the screen and the print/printer. The error message you typed in the question cannot be literally found on the web. Please turn on the printer and see if it shows the error, otherwise try starting the print again. Report back by [edit] please.
